# Integrating a 1-form over a curve C

Tags: vector-analysis

Let C be the curve in the plane parametrized by $\gamma(t)=(107cos(t)+sin(t)cos(e^{\pi t^3}), \ 107sin(t)+sin(t)sin(e^{\pi t^7})), \ t \in [0,2\pi]$.

Integrate the 1-form: $$\zeta=\frac{2xdx+2ydy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}+\frac{(x-2)dy-(y-2)dx}{(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2}$$ over C.

How do I make this integral less complicated?

Comment: Hint: is the 1-form exact? Is the curve special? You may be able to show that the integral is zero.

Comment: @SeanRoberson. It's a closed curve and the 1-form is undefined at points $(0,0)$ and $(2,2)$. The closed curve starts and ends at $(107,0)$, but I'm not sure how to tell if the curve contains those points.

Comment: @SeanRoberson. So, the closed curve C does contain $(0,0)$ and $(2,2)$. How do I show that the 1-form is exact if it is undefined in those regions of C?

Comment: You only need to look inside, not on, C.

Comment: @SeanRoberson. I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by looking inside C. Isn't $(0,0)$ and $(2,2)$ inside C?